# Hardcover YA Series from the 1980's: starship pilots keep colonists in sleep; planet where everything is disassembled

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, books, spaceship

The stories I read were in my grade school library in the mid 1980's.  The series was like an anthology with each story published in its own hardcover.  (Rather than being a single novel split up into individual chapters.)  I don't think there was any connection between the stories, other than theme, published by the same printing press. The novels didn't seem to share the same universe, but I could be mis-remembering them.

**One of the stories was about a colony ship pilot**, who wakes up find the previous pilot hadn't gone to sleep yet, but was waiting for him.  The previous pilot should have entered sleep after the end of his tour.  (I think a tour was a year?) The pilots discuss the function of the colony and the eventual use of the ship as building material on the new world.  I seem to remember that it would take 3 pilots to awaken the colonists from sleep, to start the colony.

I think the point was that the selection of the three pilots would ensure that no single pilot could go nuts and awaken the colonists early, but only after the arrival to ensure passenger safety. The end of the story was the awakened pilot discovering that the ship had landed years ago, but that not a single ship's pilot had wanted to awaken others to start the colonization.

**Another story was about a spaceship that discovered a planet where everything had been disassembled**.  That is, everything taken apart into its component pieces. The remains of the civilization on that world were visible, but anything that could have been broken down into smaller parts, was. Animals, trees, any multi-celled life was stripped into single cells. Buildings left like erector sets. Cars like unglued models, just the pieces piled together.

The visiting spaceship has one of its space-suited crew members begin to be disassembled buy an invisible force. I don't remember which character comes up with the idea that whatever had broken down the planet was still there. That character came up with the idea to broadcast in every spectrum of radio waves intermittently to attempt to show distress. That was what stopped the crew member being broken down.

**Yet another story was about a group of scientists who had discovered time travel**. And still more stories, but those are the three that stood out in my memory.

Comment: So this is one continuing series? Do you remember anything else about the plot, or about the author? We have a fair bit of [guidance for asking story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) - please read it and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: What about the time travel story? Do you remember anything about that?

Comment: I think a paradox destroyed the Universe, but don't quote me on that... :)